# Testing for exact string with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to find the exact match for the following strings;

```
/test/anyAlphaNumericId123
/test/anyAlphaNumericId123/
```

That will not match the following

```
/test/anyAlphaNumericId123/x
```

I have the following Regex currently, which matches both former cases and not the latter;

```
/(\/test\/)(.*?)(\/|$)/
```

But on attempting to call str.match on it, I will also get a result for the latter, as it has a partial match. Can I accomplish this with Regex alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the pattern as:

```
^\/test\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\/test\/` Match `/test/`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the allowed ranges
- `\/?` Match an optional `/`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zyiPoR/1)

Example using a case insensitive match with the `/i` flag:

```js
const regex = /^\/test\/[a-z0-9]+\/?$/i;
[
  "/test/anyAlphaNumericId123",
  "/test/anyAlphaNumericId123/",
  "/test/anyAlphaNumericId123/x"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(regex.test(s) ? `Match: ${s}` : `No match ${s}`)
);
```